Time and weight optimized route from a noded network
I would like to create a routing system for a park with historic buildings, using pgrouting. The goal is to allow every visitor to input parameters, after which an optimized route is calculated. These parameters are grouped into mandatory activities that have specific time constraints, and interests, such as the age of buildings. The visitor also inputs their arrival location at the park (east or west).
Parameters

Arrival time: 10:00
Time to spend at the park: 5 hours
Arrival location: East
Activities: Create butter: 12:00 - 14:00, Bread baking: 13:00
Interests: Buildings built between 1300 and 1700

My Approach
I divided the problem into two sections:

Create a route for the time-critical activities using the pgr_vrpOneDepot function.
This ensures that mandatory activities are included in the route while respecting their time constraints.

Optimize the remaining time for visiting the buildings of interest.
I assign a weight to each building (node), with higher weights for nodes that match the visitor’s interests. The goal is to create a route that maximizes the total weight within the available travel time.


Challenges (Problems):
The main challenge lies in optimizing both time and weights for the second section.
Question:
Is there a function I can use to optimize for the highest weights within a given time constraint?
Possible Solution(s):

Instead of assigning weights, I could reverse the cost by penalizing
uninteresting nodes (e.g., assigning them higher costs). Then, I
would iterate through the results and adjust until the total time
remains within the limit.
Alternatively, I could use the pgr_vrpOneDepot function for the
entire process and find a way to indicate that not every node needs
to be visited.

